# AJAX not showing data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two selects, the second one is *hidden* and it should be shown if the first select has been changed, I checked it through `on('change', function(){ ...` and it is working so far. I've checked and also showed a console.log when the first select box is changed.

The main problem here is when I picked a option from the first select box, it should send some request using **AJAX**. I've sent some request to **fetch_sections.php** and it *should* append or add data in my *second select box*.

This is my **updated** script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select').material_select();
        $('#school-list').on('change', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'fetch_sections.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {parent: $(this).val() },
                success: function(data)
                {
                    $('#section-list').empty();
                    $('#section-list').html(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
            $('#hideThis').show("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my *fetch_sections.php* (working, checked with *PostMan*):

```
<?php
    require '../assets/php/init.php';

    if ($_POST)
    {
        $schoolID   = Essentials::sanitize($_POST['parent']);

        $fetchSQL   = "SELECT `sectionid`, `name` FROM `sections` WHERE schoolid = ?";
        $fetch      = $conn->prepare($fetchSQL);
        $fetch->execute([$schoolID]);
        $fetchRes   = $fetch->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(!$fetchRes) {
            echo '
                <option value="" disabled selected>Unfortunately, there is no section here.</option>
            ';
        } else {
            foreach ($fetchRes as $section)
            {
                echo '
                    <option value="'.$section['sectionid'].'"">'.$section['name'].'</option>
                ';
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my select HTML **also updated**:

```
            <div class="row margin">
              <div class="input-field col s12">
                <select id="school-list" name="school-list">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your school</option>
                    ...
                </select>
                <label>School</label>
              </div>
            </div>
                <div class="row margin" id="hideThis" style="display:none">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <select id="section-list" name="section-list">
                      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your section</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Section</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**Update** [as suggested by *ccKep*]:

I can now see the data that I want through `console.log(data)`, the thing that it outputs is:

`<option value="9-1">9-A...</option>`, now I want to add it to my main select list but it doesn't let me.

The output should be:

```
                <select id="section-list" name="section-list">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your section</option>
                  <option value="9-1">9-A...</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Where's `parent` in your ajax call coming from? Also: You're missing the closing bracket on your success callback.

Comment: I would recommend you use console.log() or debugger tool to see if your code runs, or stucks at which part. For example, I would add console.log("this runs") before you call your ajax function and in your sucess callback function.

Comment: **I've updated the question with the Select HTML code**

Comment: @Phu Nguyen Yes, it indeed run and previously I outputted `console.log(this.value)` and seems fine to me.

Comment: `data: {parent: parent},` where have you assign value to `parent`?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I want to POST the ID that i'm getting when changing selects. I'm sorry if I'm a newbie at PHP and AJAX :(

Comment: Fix your missing closing bracket and use `data: { parent: $(this).val() },`.

Comment: Also: You might want to add `$('#section-list').empty();` before appending new stuff (or use `$('#section-list').html(data);`), otherwise everytime you change the first select you'll keep adding options to the second one.

Comment: It works, I console logged it but it doesn't append or add below the <select> tag and i'm getting the default.

Comment: Take a look at the network tab of your browser, what's the request and response you get?

Comment: I actually get the data that I want to see through `console.log(data)` and it shows `<option value="...">...</option>` but it never show it to my main.

Comment: You are sure `$('#section-list').parents(".row:eq(0)")` is giving you the right element? because the hidden `.row` is not the first child of that specific hierarchy. Why don't you just give it an `id` and use that to be certain? Relative selectors are a pain and quite error prone (since they might need to be re-done when you restructure the page)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, noted. I've assigned an ID to it and used it instead of a dirty code.

Comment: You might want to edit your questions code to show **exactly** what you have now (in case it's still not working). Also append the ajax request/response from your browsers network tab in the question.

Comment: @ccKep Thanks, I actually updated it know.

Comment: Don't see any reasons why it shouldn't work - is that page accessible online?

Comment: I will publish it online but for now it is on _localhost_

Comment: @ccKep I've tried putting it on other ID's and it works. I think this is an issue with MaterializeCSS.

Comment: Chances are MaterializeCSS hides the `<select>` and replaces it with a `<ul>` and `<li>` combinations using JS. According to the docs you can trigger an update by running `$('#section-list').material_select();` again at the end of your ajax success callback.